# How to make UIViewController slide from bottom to top without fading previous view?

Tags: swift, animation, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uikit

I am creating a new app with Swift, and would like to slide my UIViewController from bottom to top with UINavigationController, but my current solution fades out previous view.

This annoying fade looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMaJ1.jpg

I am using Swift 4.2 and XCode 10. I am testing my app on my iPhone 7 Plus with iOS 12.0.

Currently I am using this solution for pushing view from bottom to top:

```swift
let transition = CATransition()
transition.duration = 0.3
transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: 
    CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
transition.type = CATransitionType.moveIn
transition.subtype = CATransitionSubtype.fromTop
navigationController?.view.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)
navigationController?.pushViewController(LoginScreen(), animated: false)
```

and this solution for pushing from top to bottom:

```swift
// same code
transition.type = CATransitionType.reveal
transition.subtype = CATransitionSubtype.fromBottom
// same code
navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
```

I want to slide my UIViewController from bottom to top and vice-versa without fading previous UIViewController, but now my solution fades previous UIViewController.

Comment: You could use the usual modal transition when presenting the view controller. Don't push. but present. It has the default animation the one you desire. Regarding the fading of the bottom controller: as I can see from the image, your presented view controller does not cover the whole screen. How would you want the final result to look like?

Comment: @Starsky this screenshot is taken in a process of animation. When it finishes, the bottom screen covers old screen completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fade effect is the layer where you've put your animation. You are over-complicating yourself. Just instantiate the view controller and present it on top of your existing view controller.

```
let loginScreenVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginScreen") as! LoginScreen
loginScreenVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
self.present(loginScreenVC, animated: true)
//might be as well:
//navigationController?.present(loginScreenVC, animated: true)
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want to close it, just call:

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thank you! That's it. I am a beginner in iOS development so yeah. And how can I reverse this animation so login screen goes back down revealing first screen?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it best way I would suggest you is just watch these videos, here I am only sharing one link but you can get the other 2 parts on watching this video in the link : https://youtu.be/k-GvIqh5Xcs

I am sure this is surely going to be the best solution for your question. ☺️

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that's not my case. I am using not modal, but UIViewController. I just want to make transition from one view controller to another by sliding new view from bottom to top of first view controller.